# Antigua tourist visa of Indian passport holder with Swiss C-permit

Tags: visas, passports, antigua

I am an Indian passport holder, permanently residing in Switzerland on C-permit (permanent residency).

Do I need a tourist visa to visit Antigua&Barbuda or can I visit there without a visa ?

Comment: Are you a Swiss citizen or Indian citizen? I don't believe India recognizes dual citizenship.

Comment: @MichaelC. I am an Indian national, I don't have the Swiss citizenship yet.

Answer (score 1):

According to Timatic, Passengers with a **valid visa** issued by a **Schengen Member State** or United Kingdom are Visa exempted for a stay of 30 days. Visa waiver fee: USD 100.
https://www.emirates.com/english/plan_book/find_visa_requirements/visa_passport_information_results.aspx?NC=IN&NV=India&DC=AG&DV=Antigua+and+Barbuda&h=8a2085e8650c1af69a576ed085f0919824d18

Answer (score 0):

> Please note that citizens of the following Commonwealth countries now
>   require a visa for entry into Antigua and Barbuda: Bangladesh,
>   Cameroon, The Gambia, Ghana, India, Mozambique, Nigeria, Pakistan,
>   Sierra Leone and Sri Lanka.

http://cip.gov.ag/how-to-apply/passport-visa-requirements/